# Pyspark how to add row number in dataframe without changing the order?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a column with row number for the below dataframe, but keep the original order.

The existing dataframe:

```
+-—-+
|val|
+-—-+
|1.0|
+-—-+
|0.0|
+-—-+
|0.0|
+-—-+
|1.0|
+-—-+
|0.0|
+-—-+
```

My expected output:

```
+-—-+-—-+
|idx|val|
+-—-+-—-+
|  1|1.0|
+-—-+-—-+
|  2|0.0|
+-—-+-—-+
|  3|0.0|
+-—-+-—-+
|  4|1.0|
+-—-+-—-+
|  5|0.0|
+-—-+-—-+
```

I had tried many codes like the below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,lit
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))
df = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(w))
```

```
Window.partitionBy("xxx").orderBy("yyy")
```

But the above code just only `groupby` the value and set index, which will make my df not in order.

Can we just add one column without changing the order?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing as order in Apache Spark, it is a distributed system where data is divided into smaller chunks called partitions, each operation will be applied to these partitions, the creation of partitions is random, so you will not be able to preserve order unless you specified in your orderBy() clause, so if you need to keep order you need to specify which column will be used to keep order.

Answer (score 0):

Oh just tried another method and it works, please tell me when I am wrong in some other case.

df_test01 is the dataframe as above

```
rdd = df_test01.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1],) + x[0])
df_test02 = rdd.toDF(["row_number", "value"])
display(df_test02)
```

Comment: this might work for smaller data but for larger data, it gets partitioned and you have no way to know which partition will be used in what sequence.

Comment: Agree. In distributed computing, the ordering is an issue, the ordering is done at the higher level when the output of your operation is being taken from executors into the driver to be re-calculated.